# Play animation frame by frame then pausing Python

Tags: python, animation, operator

I want to play animation as long as a specific condition is true, once the condition is false the animation will be paused and a specific function will run. The problem is that when I run the below code I find blender pausing (hanging) then jumping to frame 70 straight away (as the condition is always false, which is fine) instead of playing frame by frame. Any thoughts how I can run the animation normally frame by frame through python then pausing it when needed?

```
i = 0
while i < 70:
   if condition == True:
     #go to next frame
     scene.frame_set(scene.frame_current + 1)
   else:
     #pause animation and call my function   
     myfunc()                
   i += 1
```

Comment: What you are seeing is expected behaviour of your operator above.  Consider using a frame_change handler, or a modal timer operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @batFINGER, `frame_change` handler was used as shown below:

```
def my_handler(scene):
    retVal = myFunc()
    myFunc2(retVal)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```